# Persisting a Receipt in iCloud using CloudKit in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cloudkit, icloud-api

#### #1

I'm developing iOS App with a non-renewing subscription in it.
I want to make the subscription available on all of the user’s devices and to let users restore the purchase.

As said in Apple's docs:

> For non-renewing subscriptions, use iCloud or your own server to keep
>   a persistent record.

I do not what to use my own server because my App is available only for iOS for now. So iCloud seems to be easer solution.

After watching and reading A LOT of WWDC videos and docs about iCloud seems like the best solution for me is CloudKit because Key-value storage is limited to 1MB and I have a big chances to get total data size bigger than this per one user (after a year of different purchases for ex.).

Question is: **am I right so far?**

#### #2

I'm using RMStore Library for purchases. As is it said in docs RMStore doesn't have reference implementation of Transaction persistence to iCloud and I couldn't find any examples in the Internet so I'll have to do it by my own from scratch.

The first problem staring me in the face is: **what if there will be some problem syncing the receipt to iCloud after user has purchased the subscription?** For example: user bought the subscription, got some error syncing it to iCloud, closed the App and that's it. **Is this a real scenario?** For non-renewing subscriptions receipt is not stored anywhere by Apple so I am fully responsible for delivering and saving it for my user. **Should I immediately save the receipt in `NSUserDefaults` or in Keychain after transaction is finished to be able to compare synced data to local one next time user launches the App? Or maybe I should not 'Finish the transaction' until receipt is synced?** I could not find any guides from Apple for this...

#### #3

The next obvious question is: **Can user clear my App's iCloud private storage?** Can user somehow delete stored in the iCloud receipt thereby deleting all information about his purchases? **If yes - how should I handle it?** If this scenario is real I have no way to recover his purchase and open App's functionality for him until he buys subscription again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK, I found answer for question #2 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW10) It is said that I should finish the transaction only after Persisting is finished.

Comment: What do you do though if the user blocks your app's access to iCloud? Should you fall back on NSUserDefaults or Keychain?

Answer (score 2):

1. CloudKit is not limited to 1MB. A record is limited. But if you have more than 1MB of data in a record, you should consider a refactor. If it's just some sort of data blob, then you should save it in a CKAsset. For that the limitations is much higher.
2. Syncing will be a problem no matter what technique you use. One way to improve on that is by registering a begin purchase flag, then do the purchase and after that set the purchased flag. Then if a record stays in the 'begin purchase' state you know something went wrong and you can check with the App Store if the purchase was successful.
3. you should add a restore purchases function to your app